# Handle a javascript popup inside a div

Tags: javascript, webdriver, alert, handle

If you click on this link http://www.interflora.fr/fleurs-naissance-maman/cadeau-orchidee-champagne-veuve-cliquot-vintage/PRIX-UNIQUE/FR
then on the yellow button "Commander"
a popup shows up
But I really don't know how to handle it.

I tried WindowHandles like below

```
String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
     subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); 

System.out.println("popup : " + subWindowHandler);
```

but before or after clicking on "Commander", we are still on the same page "subWindowHandler" so it's not about WindowHandles

When I click on "Commander", it triggers a javascript
Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addToCartPdp').click(function () {
                var prixLibre = parseInt($( "#prixLibre" ).val());
                var smallPrice = parseInt($( "#smallPrice" ).val());
                var formattedSmallPrice = $( "#smallPrice" ).attr('title');
                var length_accessoires = 3;
                $( "#msgSmallPrice" ).text(formattedSmallPrice);
                if((prixLibre < smallPrice || prixLibre > 1000) && $('#radioPrixLibre').is(':checked'))
                {
                    $.colorbox({
                        html: $( "#popupPrixLibre" ).html(), 
                        overlayClose: false, 
                        escKey: false,
                        onLoad: function () {
                            $( "#msgSmallPrice").text(formattedSmallPrice);
                        },
                        onComplete: function () {
                        $( "#msgSmallPrice").text(formattedSmallPrice);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if( length_accessoires <= 0)
                {
                     $( "#addAccToCartForm" ).submit();
                }
                else if($("#addAccToCartFormCarousel input[name='accessoiresCodes']:checked").length == length_accessoires)
                {
                    $( "#addAccToCartFormCarousel" ).submit();
                }
                else
                {
                        $.colorbox({
                        html: $( "#popupAccessoire" ).html(), overlayClose: false, escKey: false,
                        onLoad: function () {
                            $('#cboxClose').remove();
                        },
                        onComplete: function () {
                            var totalProduct = $('.inputCheckAcc').size();
                            var totalProductChecked = 0;
                            $('.inputCheckAcc').each(function () {
                                var elem = $(this);
                                var currentAcc = $('#productCodePost-' + elem.val());
                                if (currentAcc.length && currentAcc.parent('label').hasClass('checOn')) {
                                    elem.parent().parent().parent().hide();
                                    elem.prop('checked', true);
                                    elem.parent('label').removeClass('checOff').addClass('checOn');
                                    totalProductChecked++;
                                }
                                else {
                                    elem.prop('checked', false);
                                    elem.parent('label').removeClass('checOn').addClass('checOff');
                                }
                            });
                            $(".BtnJ").eq(1).on('click', function(){
                               $(".BtnJ").eq(1).prop("disabled",true);
                               $(".BtnJ").eq(1).off("click");
                               $('.acc_add_to_cart_form').eq(2).submit();
                             });
                            $('.acc_add_to_cart_form').preventDoubleSubmission(); 

                        },
                        scrolling: false
                    });
                    loadchekedStyle();
                }
       });
 });
 $("#addAccToCartFormCarousel").preventDoubleSubmission();
```

I tried to manage that with Alert but it still didn't work.
I'm running out of idea.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not new window and not alert, it's just popup on the same page. So you can wait for popup is visible on the page and then work with it. Here's example of closing it on java:

```
WebdriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
//Wait for popup is visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='cboxLoadedContent']")));
//Close popup
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='cboxLoadedContent']//a[@id='btnCrossPopup']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you Mykhail Filonchenko. I really appreciate your help.
It's working as expected now.
Thanks again for your time.